# Как добавить время в миллисекундах в БД

Tags: база-данных, calendar, sqlite

Пишу приложение для мониторинга своих покупок и в дальнейшем вывода статистики по динамике цен и т.д. Погуглив, решил дату покупки записывать в БД в качестве числа long.
Есть такой код

```
 // selection of the desired date
public void desiredDate(View v){
    showDialog(DIALOG_DATE);
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DATE:
            // set date picker as current date
            return new DatePickerDialog(this, datePickerListener,
                    year, month,day);
    }
    return null;
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;
        // Установим выбранную дату и получим число миллисекунд
        selectedDate.setTimeInMillis(345672535123564l);
        longDate = selectedDate.getTimeInMillis();

        // set selected date into textview
        tvDate.setText(new StringBuilder().append(day)
                .append("-").append(month + 1).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));
    }
};
```

Переменную selectedDate типа Calendar, инициализировал так - getInstance(). На 345672535123564l не стоит обращать внимания, так как просто проверял установит какую-нибудь дату или нет. Проблема в том, что longDate всегда 0.
Я пробовал и так

```
selectedDate.set(selectedYear, selectedMonth, selectedDay);
```

и так

```
selectedDate.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
```

ничего не выходит. Думаю пробовать уже через класс Date, но может опытные люди подскажут как решить эту проблему?
Добавлю, что в будущем хочу получить статистику (например, за год) по динамике цены на определённый товар и выбирать дату я буду из БД естественно. На сколько удобно и легко-тяжело это будет сделать новичку, сохраняя дату числом типа long? Может есть лучше вариант?

Comment: Сделал небольшой тест и насколько я понял, мы работаем с копиями значений, а не с самими значениями (забыл как правильно это называется). Как же мне тогда поступить? Как выбранную дату перевести в миллисекунды? И стоит ли в таком виде сохранять дату в БД?

Comment: в большинстве баз есть соответствующие типы полей для хранения даты и времени, а также функции для получения текущей даты/времени - проще воспользоваться ими

Answer (score 1):

Для хранения даты можно использовать текстовое ее представление, поддерживаются в т.ч. и миллисекунды

YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS

подробней
https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: Спасибо. А как в таком случае мне потом извлекать данные из БД за определенный период?

Comment: SELECT * FROM test WHERE date BETWEEN "2015-01-01 10:00:00.000" AND "2015-02-01 10:00:00.999";